# How to install igraph package for python in ubuntu?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, igraph

I tried to install igraph package for python in ubuntu, and i followed these steps:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:igraph/ppa
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install python-igraph

Then I checked that the igraph module is installed in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/

but when I import the module in python... the error is:

ImportError: No module named igraph

What to do import the package and use it?

Comment: What does `which python` give you?

Comment: @AndreyShipilov it gives me  /usr/local/bin/python

Comment: Which means `apt-get` installed the module to other directory.

Comment: How to change the installation directory?

Comment: You shouldn't do it. You should set global python as a default one. How did you install it on the first place?

Comment: Also, make sure that the core is installed: `sudo apt-get install igraph`